# Can you be ill from an injury (I don't mean an infection)

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-usage

This is something that crops up on the BBC a lot and irks me. For example, from [a story](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-36343415) today:

> One woman is critically ill and three others have been injured after
>   they were stabbed near a supermarket car park in west London.

To me, you are ill (or sick) if you have, for example, contracted a disease and using it in the sense of someone being injured is wrong.

Google gives the definition of ill as "suffering from an illness or disease or feeling unwell." and I'm sure that a car crash or stabbing would certainly make you feel unwell, but I still don't think it's right. Is it?

Comment: For the most part I tend to agree with you. I am no medic but I suspect if the injuries lead to a critical condition, that complicating factors may predispose doctors to refer to the patient being *ill*. That's what I am reading between the lines here.

Comment: Dictionaries - including online dictionaries - are a far better and more reliable source of word definitions than 'Google'!!!

Comment: Generally, one sees "critically injured" in a situation like that, at least in the US press.

Comment: @TrevorD Google's "define:word" command gives extensive definitions and other information about a word and is a useful short cut to quickly get the meaning of a word. Although I can't find a list of sources it uses, I'm pretty sure they are from valid and recognised sources of such information.

Comment: @TrevorD if you check with Oxford Dictionaries (online), 9 times out of 10 the definitions are the same.

Comment: @Darren You merely said "Google gives the definition" - that is an open ended and ambiguous statement. On this forum, a definition that *clearly* comes from a recognised standard dictionary carries rather more weight than the ambiguous 'Google'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks. I use them & *Chambers*. I wasn't aware of the Google "define:word" command. But just referring to 'Google' is so ambiguous, and I'm inclined to dismiss definitions unless we know the *original* source.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, the selected answer on that other question gives a very clear and thoughtful response that makes sense. Thanks. Interesting that both that question and mine are in response to the BBC. Maybe their MoS gives a different usage to most other media outlets.

Comment: HuffingtonPostUK: [Two Men Intervened To Save Pregnant Woman **Critically Ill After Stabbing**](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2016/03/05/pregnant-woman-critically-ill-after-being-stabbed_n_9384582.html). I don't think this is some peculiarity of the Beeb - it's just a usage that occurs more often in the media than in ordinary spoken contexts. Maybe because newspapers would always tend to prefer short & snappy ***ill*** over ***injured*** (particularly for headlines, where brevity is at a premium).

Comment: @MikeHarris Given the way that the body can respond to severe trauma, it must often become a moot point as to whether someone at death's door is ill or injured!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the meanings of *ill* is simply the antonym of *well*.  In this case the word does apply in your example.  An injured person isn't *well*.

You are right however, in that it is more common for *ill* to refer to an illness.  The BBC does frequently in its reports state "*One woman is in a critical condition...*".  This is often a direct quote from a hospital announcement and makes no reference to the cause of the condition.

Of course, for less critical situations, the word *indisposed* covers both illness and injury.

Answer (score 3):

*[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ill_2#ill_4)* defines it as

> not healthy, because of a medical condition or **an injury** (emphasis added)

Other online dictionaries talk about poor health, not precluding injury as a cause.

Also, the term *terminally ill* seems to be used for patients near death, regardless of the cause.

[The above relates to AmE. Can't speak for BrE]

Comment: Yes, I think most definitions (American and British) could be interpreted in such a way as to make it _technically_ correct, but in everyday usage I don't think most people would use it that way. Or maybe it's just me!

Comment: @bib BrE usage is similar. One might say "critically injured", but the usage of "ill" in that context is not uncommon.

Comment: @Darren I think there is a case that news reporting of a medical opinion isn't 'everyday usage', most people wouldn't use 'critically' when talking about a level of illness either.. I'd say that in this instance the BBC are reporting a medical opinion, probably using the language that the hospital used in its communication with the press.

Answer (score 0):

As regards the incident, mentioned by the OP, the report in today's Guardian starts:

*A woman was critically ill in hospital after a man stabbed shoppers in the car park of a supermarket...*

One advantage of using *ill* is that it is a more flexible word than *injured* when describing an ongoing condition.

*Injured* does not lend itself to expressions like *remains ill*, *has now become very ill*, is *critically ill* *is recovering* etc. Saying someone is *injured* whilst appropriate to an immediate announcement, becomes awkward to use after the patient has been in hospital for a few days.

If the *injury* leads to a critical stay in hospital, *illness* seems a more versatile descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible that a physical injury causes an illness. Quite common when the physical assault triggers a mental problem. (For example, if someone was attacked, all injuries heal, and now that person is ill and incapable of leaving their home without panic attacks). Another obvious way is getting ill after being stabbed with an infected knife, or maybe an infected needle used by a drug user.